# which datatype we need use for inserting amount like 10.00 format in php

Tags: php, mysql

i have designed like this i need to create a table to insert the amount in the format of Rs.10.00. how to create the table for this?

```
function validategop()
{

    var depo_amt=parseInt(document.getElementById("depo_amt").value);

    document.getElementById("depo_amt").value='Rs.'+depo_amt+'.00'

}
 <input type="text" name="depo_amt" id="depo_amt"  maxlength="70" placeholder="0.00" onblur="validategop();"/>
```

Comment: You could have googled instead of posting it as a question.

Comment: i tried that but if i browse that.. it is showing as 0.00

Comment: it is not showing wat i inserted

Comment: generally you don't put formatted numbers into a database because `'Rs.'+depo_amt+'.00'` produces a string instead of a number.

Comment: @Jorg : If it's send as a http parameter it's a string anyway ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK Hah, true :) harder to convert with stuff attached to it though.

Comment: It's 0.00 I'm guessing because `(float)'Rs 10.00'` returns `0.00`.

Answer (score 0):

decimal(4,2) will work for you.

In your query you can call it like concatenate('Rs. ',price) if your columns name is "price decimal(4,2)".